# My code is supposed to have the child output sent to the parent. Both processes exec(). It just freezes

Tags: c, operating-system

(Please see my final code below; working version after visiting professor)

Program sets up a child-TO-parent pipe; the child proceeds with an 'exec' to perform a "pre" process and its output is connected to the pipe connected to the parent, which proceeds with an 'exec' to perform a "sort" process.

CHANGES SO FAR: The code is still freezing. I changed my exec() calls and made other changes too.

Not sure where the issue lies.

#### First revision

```
/*
 Student: Douglas Adolph
 Course: Operating Systems
 Project #: 1: Part2_childToParent.c

*/

/* The second example of pipe, between a parent and a child*/
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MSGSIZE 512

int main()
{
    char inbuf[MSGSIZE];
    int p[2];
    pid_t pid;

    if (pipe(p) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe call"); // from example code pipe2.c
        exit(1);
    }

    switch(pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork call"); // from example code pipe2.c
        exit(2);
    case 0: // child writes to pipe
        dup2(p[1], STDOUT_FILENO); // redirect standard output and error output
        close(p[0]); // close link
        close(p[1]);
        execlp("./pre", "pre",(char *)0); // call execl() to execute pre.c
        perror("execl() failed!");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    default: // parent reads from pipe
        close(p[1]);
        dup2(p[0], STDIN_FILENO); // redirect standard input and error input
        execlp("./sort", "sort",(char *)0); // call execl() to execute sort.c
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

#### Next revision

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MSGSIZE 512

int main()
{
    char inbuf[MSGSIZE];
    int p[2];
    pid_t pid;

    if (pipe(p) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe call"); // from example code pipe2.c
        exit(1);
    }

    switch(pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork call"); // from example code pipe2.c
        exit(2);
    case 0: // child writes to pipe
        dup(p[1]); // redirect standard output and error output
        close(p[0]); // close link
        //close(p[1]);
        execl("./pre", "pre",(char *)0); // call execl() to execute pre.c
        perror("execl() failed!");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    default: // parent reads from pipe
        wait((int *)0);
        close(p[1]);
        if ((n = read(p[0], inbuf, MSGSIZE)) >= 0) {
            printf("in buff");
            inbuf[n] = 0; // terminate the string
            printf("%s\n", inbuf); // print message
        }
        execl("./sortC", "sortC",(char *)0); // call execl() to execute sort.c
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Final code after visiting professor, confirming requirements, and running code successfully:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MSGSIZE 512

int main() {
    char inbuf[MSGSIZE];
    int p[2];
    pid_t pid;

    if (pipe(p) == -1) {
        perror("pipe call"); // from example code pipe2.c
        exit(1);
    }

    switch(pid = fork()) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork call"); // from example code pipe2.c
            exit(2);
        case 0: // child writes to pipe
            close(1);
            dup(p[1]); // redirect standard output and error output
            close(p[0]);
            close(p[1]);
            execl("./pre", "pre",(char *)0); // call execl() to execute pre.c
            perror("execl() failed!");
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        default: // parent reads from pipe
            close(0);
            dup(p[0]);
            close(p[0]);
            close(p[1]);
            execl("./sort", "sort", (char *)0);    // call execl() to execute sort.c
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: The child is supposed to execute pre.c (I made an executable named preC). The output from that file is supposed to be sent to the parent process, who reads and outputs the data. Then, the parent is supposed to call sort.c (executable named sortC) and execute it. I'm getting no feedback when I run it; the terminal just shows a blank line.

Comment: `read(p[0], inbuf, MSGSIZE);` won't terminate the string you're expecting to get.  In fact, it can read anything from 1 to `MSGSIZE` bytes.

Comment: Also, `wait((int *)0);` after `execl("/sortC", (char *)0);` won't work.  If the `execl()` works, the entire process is replaced by the newly-exec'd binary.

Comment: The names `/sortC` and `/preC` are dubious; you shouldn't be writing in the root directory.  Did you mean `./sortC` and `./preC`, which are the programs in the current directory?  You should put error printing code after the `execl()` calls, to report failure to `execl()`.  Also, it is aconventional to decline to give your sort process an `argv[0]` value such as `"sortC"`.  You did it right with `preC`.

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I terminate the string, then?

Comment: In terms of the wait(), should that be called at all, or somewhere else?

Comment: In this program, there's no need to call `wait()` at all.  You should strictly close the second end of the pipe after you use `dup2()` to map it to one of the standard I/O channels.  You'll probably be OK in this context, but it often matters.  Incidentally, the `exit(0);` will only be reached if one of the `execl()` calls fails, so it should probably be `exit(1);` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` — or I'd prefer `return(1);` or `return(EXIT_FAILURE);` (with or without parentheses; I'm not fussed about them).

Comment: Are you asking me about 'how to terminate the string'?  I simply meant that you should be using `execl("./sortC", "sortC", (char *)0);` to parallel your use of `execl("./preC", "preC", (char *)0);` — where I've just taken liberties with the executable name.  (Incidentally, you can address a comment to a particular person by starting it with `@Jonathan` or `@Andrew` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I have so far regarding changes, but it still freezes when I run it:

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I made the changes to exec like you mentioned. The file I'm trying to execute is pre.c and sort.c . I've made executables preC and sortC.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How do I paste my code as a comment? It keeps coming up all smushed together.

Comment: So, the files you're trying to execute are `preC` and `sortC`. You don't execute the C files but you do execute the executables created from the C files.  The best way to show what you've changed is to update the question with the new information, usually leaving the old intact.  (Leaving the old intact is crucial if anyone has answered; it isn't quite so crucial when you've only received comments, as here, but it is generally better.)  You can't format code in comments meaningfully.  Don't even bother trying.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Going to edit my above code with the changes I've made. Can't seem to comment the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I updated my code. It gave me grief about too much code when I kept the original, so I removed it. I'm not sure why it is still freezing, but am I even doing the exec() calls right? I'm assuming I have to pass the argument to execute (i.e. ./a.out, preC, etc.).

Comment: The code in the 'parent' fragment is a bit peculiar.  You read the information from the child.  Then you print it.  (There are problems because the information read is probably not null terminated.  You should take care of the by recording the result of `read()` — if you keep the `read()`.)  Then you run `sortC`.  Shouldn't you be redirecting the read end of the pipe to standard input before executing `sortC` and not reading anything in the parent code?

Comment: My child is supposed to execute pre.c and the output is supposed to be sent to the parent who executes sort.c. I'm not sure if sort.c is supposed to sort the input from the child's exec. It seems likely that that is what I'm supposed to do, but the sort.c program asks the user to input names to be sorted from the keyboard, so I think I'm just supposed to have the parent execute sort.c as it is, but I'm not sure. In terms of recording the result of read(), how do I do that? Sorry for so many questions!

Answer (score 2):

#### Round 1

Here's a mildly modified version of your updated code — tagged 'first revision' in the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MSGSIZE 512

int main(void)
{
    //char inbuf[MSGSIZE];
    int p[2];

    if (pipe(p) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe call"); // from example code pipe2.c
        exit(1);
    }

    switch (fork())
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork call");     // from example code pipe2.c
        exit(2);
    case 0:     // child writes to pipe
        dup2(p[1], STDOUT_FILENO);     // redirect standard output and error output
        close(p[0]);     // close link
        close(p[1]);
        execl("./preC", "preC", (char *)0);    // call execl() to execute pre.c
        perror("execl() failed!");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    default:     // parent reads from pipe
        close(p[1]);
        dup2(p[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(p[0]);
        // read(p[0], inbuf, MSGSIZE); // read message in pipe (sent from child)
        // printf("%s\n", inbuf); // print message
        execl("./sortC", "sortC", (char *)0);    // call execl() to execute sort.c
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /*NOTREACHED*/

    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The primary changes are:

1. Closing the second end of the pipe after the call to `dup2()`.
2. Revising the code in the parent branch to rework the I/O redirection.

This compiles without warnings under my preferred stringent compilation options (on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 still, with GCC 7.2.0):

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    fork79.c -o fork79
```

I created a pair of minimal shell scripts to work as `preC` and `sortC`:

```
$ cat preC
#!/bin/sh
exec ls -t *.c
$ cat sortC
#!/bin/sh
exec sort
$
```

The basic output from `preC` is:

```
fork79.c        pth47.c         cpp13.c         th89.c          mnmx67.c
pl53.c          pth23.c         fd19.c          cp53.c          mm19.c
da73.c          bs79.c          fd53.c          th59.c          mm53.c
example.c       pm73.c          fd23.c          th19.c          mm23.c
rf13.c          nr13.c          fd97.c          cp41.c          mm59.c
pipe97.c        cola83.c        fd47.c          mnmx71.c        bst29.c
pipe83.c        cola61.c        cp79.c          mergesort47.c
```

(When the output is piped, the file names are listed one per line.)

The output from running `fork97` (created by compiling `fork79.c` as shown) is:

```
bs79.c
bst29.c
cola61.c
cola83.c
cp41.c
cp53.c
cp79.c
cpp13.c
da73.c
example.c
fd19.c
fd23.c
fd47.c
fd53.c
fd97.c
fork79.c
mergesort47.c
mm19.c
mm23.c
mm53.c
mm59.c
mnmx67.c
mnmx71.c
nr13.c
pipe83.c
pipe97.c
pl53.c
pm73.c
pth23.c
pth47.c
rf13.c
th19.c
th59.c
th89.c
```

This shows that the output is sorted by name from `sortC`.

---

#### Round 2

After discussion, it seems that it will be best if the original process forks and executes the `preC` process with a pipe from the standard output of the `preC` read from the original process.  Then the original process should execute the `sortC` process.

To support this exercise, I created a data file `data` containing:

```
abyssinian
yosemite
sierra
high
ocelot
jaguar
tiger
lion
leopard
snow leopard
puma
panther
cougar
```

I created a revised program from the source `fork31.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MSGSIZE 512

int main(void)
{
    int p[2];

    if (pipe(p) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe call"); // from example code pipe2.c
        exit(1);
    }

    switch (fork())
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork call");     // from example code pipe2.c
        exit(2);
    case 0:     // child writes to pipe
        dup2(p[1], STDOUT_FILENO);     // redirect standard output and error output
        close(p[0]);     // close link
        close(p[1]);
        execl("./preC", "preC", (char *)0);    // call execl() to execute pre.c
        perror("execl() failed!");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    default:     // parent reads from pipe
        {
        close(p[1]);
        int nbytes;
        char inbuf[MSGSIZE];
        while ((nbytes = read(p[0], inbuf, MSGSIZE)) > 0)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, inbuf, nbytes);
        close(p[0]);
        execl("./sortC", "sortC", (char *)0);    // call execl() to execute sort.c
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    /*NOTREACHED*/

    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This is close to the revised code in 'next revision' in the question.  The primary difference is the use of `>` instead of `>=` to recognize `EOF`.  With the low-level (file descriptor) I/O function `read()`, EOF is indicated by zero bytes read; `-1` indicates an error, and EOF is not an error.  I also use `write()` to write the data to the standard output.

I changed `preC` shell script to use `ls -Ct *.c` to reduce the amount of output.

The result of invoking was:

```
$ fork31 < data
fork31.c        pipe83.c        cola61.c        cp79.c          mergesort47.c
fork79.c        pth47.c         cpp13.c         th89.c          mnmx67.c
pl53.c          pth23.c         fd19.c          cp53.c          mm19.c
da73.c          bs79.c          fd53.c          th59.c          mm53.c
example.c       pm73.c          fd23.c          th19.c          mm23.c
rf13.c          nr13.c          fd97.c          cp41.c          mm59.c
pipe97.c        cola83.c        fd47.c          mnmx71.c        bst29.c
abyssinian
cougar
high
jaguar
leopard
lion
ocelot
panther
puma
sierra
snow leopard
tiger
yosemite
$
```

The output from the `ls` is no longer sorted by a secondary sort, of course.  The list of names fed to `sortC` from `data` was sorted as expected.  Note that if `ls` read from its standard input, this would not have worked — the sort process would have gotten no data to sort.  Fortunately, `ls` is a data generator — it doesn't read its standard input.

Comment: Thank you so much! So, the first file (pre c) is supposed to have you input names and GPAs, and it lists all GPAs that are above 3.0. The next program, sort.c is supposed to have me input student names, and it ouputs them sorted. When I run the code, it's having me do the sort.c input for student names, but it doesn't have me input for pre.c before that. Any ideas?

Comment: Mostly it makes no sense to pipe the output of `preC` (`pre.c`) to the input of `sortC` (`sortC.c`).  If you need to do interactive input to `preC`, then you probably don't want it to write prompts to the pipe, and outputting the GPAs above 3.0 doesn't make for good input to a program that expects student names.  It's not hard to design code to work in pipelines, but code does have to be designed to do so, and interactive input is often not a part of the equation.  You should take another look at the design of `preC` and `sortC`; they are currently not intended for use with each other.

Comment: I'm updating the code above now. What changes could I make to execute pre.c on its own, and after I'm done, have the parent execute sort.c separately? These are the only instructions I have:                                 Write a c program to set up a child-TO-parent pipe; the child
should 'exec' to perform a "pre" process and its output should be
connected to the pipe connected to the parent, which should 'exec' to
perform a "sort" process.

Comment: The code I showed does the setup to execute a `preC` process and pipe the output to a `sortC` process.  What you need to do is write a suitable `preC` process; something that generates data without further input from the user (like the `ls` command generates a list of file names from a list of directory names).  And you need to write a suitable `sortC` process that sorts its input.  The system `sort` program is the simplest way to sort data.  Generating the data — there are a myriad ways to do that.

Comment: Okay. For my project, I submit pre.c and sort.c the way they are (i.e. prompting user for input and either displaying 3.0+ gpas or displaying student names in alphabetical order. So, when I'm calling my exec() function, I'm having to use the pre.c and sort.c files as they are (i.e. the i/o they have). Just need to figure out how to execute the file (and input from terminal) and have the output printed by the parent, and then how to have my parent execute sort.c after displaying what child sent. Sorry if this is a mess. You've been so helpful!

Comment: OK.  Then your original design is more nearly correct.  You should read from the pipe in the parent until you get EOF, echoing the data to standard output.  Then close the pipe; you won’t be using it again.  Then exec the sort process.  It isn’t particularly orthodox as a way of doing things, but it appears to meet your requirements.

Comment: I've updated my code above to try to get it working as per your instructions. It's not quite right yet. Any ideas? Thanks again for taking so much of your time to help me! You're awesome!

Comment: See my answer update.  Once you have any answers, you cannot change the code in the question to invalidate the answers.  I rolled back your change that replaced the code, and then made an extra edit that added the code you'd added.  I don't know what was causing the system to be obstreperous with you, but it allowed me to do it.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. It's all running, save for one strange issue: whenever the sort is called and outputted, the names are not always in alphabetical order (although they are in alphabetical order when I run sort.c independently). Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `sort` or `sortC`?  There's a system command `sort` that you might be invoking which sorts (funnily enough).  You'd have to worry about: is your sort code called; what does it get as input; what does it write as output?  You could echo the input to standard error; you could echo the output to standard error as well as standard output.  You could tag each of the echoed lines with `I:` for input and `O:` for output, for example.  Then look to see where the problem is, and take it from there.